# AWS API Gateway VPC Link : accessing private HTTP API from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am trying to access to an HTTP API (under private network) from AWS API Gateway.
I created VPC link and its available.
I am getting error

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid VpcLink id {xxxxxx} referenced in integration`

Followed AWS documentation for creating VPC and API Gateway.